# Rust meta / compound structs with marker traits

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have multiple existing structs that I want to share between code contexts using a pubsub mechanism with shared "topics" (where each topic publishes a single type).  Many topics reuse the same struct types, so I'd like to somehow mark the original structs to reuse them for those topics.   Something like:

```
trait TopicMeta {
    const TOPIC: &'static str;
}

struct Point {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}

impl TopicMeta for Point as HomeLocation  {
    const TOPIC: &'static str = "home";
}

impl TopicMeta for Point as RoverLocation  {
    const TOPIC: &'static str = "rover";
}
```

However, as far as I can tell there's no way to do this?

Other options:

- I could create a new type for each topic, identical to the original Point struct except for its name.
- I could create a wrapper object for each topic with an inner field that contains the Point.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to add a field to your type and use unit `struct` as tags:

```rust
trait TopicMeta {
    const TOPIC: &'static str;
}

struct Point<T> {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
    tag: T,
}

struct HomeLocation;
struct RoverLocation;

impl TopicMeta for Point<HomeLocation> {
    const TOPIC: &'static str = "home";
}

impl TopicMeta for Point<RoverLocation> {
    const TOPIC: &'static str = "rover";
}
```